# Failed cURL command on Heroku Scheduler

Tags: curl, heroku

I have a scheduled job set to run on *Heroku Scheduler*. The command I have set is `curl -s http://example.com/cron/abc123xyz456`.

However, although the scheduler attempts to run the task it fails. Here's the log.

```
Starting process with command `curl -s http://example.com/cron/abc123xyz456`
State changed from starting to up
State changed from up to complete
Process exited with status 2
curl: option -s http://example.com/cron/abc123xyz456: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

My URL works. Is it the curl command that fails? or what is it?

Comment: Check with curl command if it is installed on server which scheduler is using

Comment: Yes, `heroku run curl https://google.com` gets a response.

Comment: ...however, `heroku run curl -s https://google.com` returns _No such size as https://google.com_, whereas  `heroku run curl --silent https://google.com` gets a response. I'll try it without the `-s` flag tomorrow and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Yes give it try without -s

Comment: It did not work with the `--silent` flag either. Same error. I have removed the flag completely. I'll see what happens tomorrow (it is scheduled to run daily).

Comment: It works with `heroku run curl http://example.com/cron/abc123xyz456` so it's a problem with Heroku Scheduler.